# Specify a Root Path of your HTML directory for script links?

Tags: html, path

I'm writing a template for dreamweaver, and don't want to change the scripts for subfolder pages.

Is there a way to make the path relative to the root directory?

for example:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="**root**/style.css" />
```

Instead of `**root**` above, I want a default path there.  Is there any way to do anything like this?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

To be relative to the root directory, just start the URI with a `/`

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
<script src="/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Then add the subfolder it is in! /subfolder/script.js!

Comment: the html file is under  site/folder/index.html   the css is site/style.css   using "/style.css" does not load the css for the indexes of subfolders

Comment: Given a stylesheet at `http://example.com/style.css` and a document at `http://example.com/folder/index.html` that references `/style.css` then it will load just fine.

Comment: except its not, all i asked- is a way to get the root path- not sure why thats so hard, but for the last time what your saying is not working

Comment: It should do. It isn't hard to get the root, `/` just works. It is a basic feature of relative URIs.

Comment: @Ted — It works fine with virtual directories, they are handled entirely under the hood. Starting a URI with `/` will always go to the root directory of the HTTP servers hierarchy. Naturally, if you have a server configuration that maps your URLs onto a the server's file system in a way that is more complicated than "`/` is `/var/www/htroot/`" those rules will get applied to the resulting URI.

Comment: @Quentin - I tried /my.css in http://localhost/myvirtual/mypage.aspx, and it points to http://localhost/my.css. So, as I said, it doesn't work

Comment: @Ted — That's what it is supposed to do!

Comment: @Gazow: If your website is not in the root directory, but in the subdirectory `site/folder/`, you can use the HTML `<base>` element, as mentioned in my answer below. Then you don't need to prepend `/site/folder/` to every single URL, as you declare it only once in the `href` attribute of the `<base>` tag.

Comment: @Gazow That also effects relative link urls... not a good idea.

Answer (score 60):

I recommend using the HTML [`<base>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base):

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.example.com/default/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

In this example, the stylesheet is located in `http://www.example.com/default/style.css`, the script in `http://www.example.com/default/script.js`. The advantage of `<base>` over `/` is that it is more flexible. Your whole website can be located in a subdirectory of a domain, and you can easily alter the default directory of your website.

Comment: Perfect for testing on different directories & routing!

Comment: this is exactly the solution i was looking for. i had a template with all the .html in the root folder, and wanted to move some to a subfolder, but that broke every link in them. no need to refactor with this!

Answer (score 34):

`/` means the root of the current drive;

`./` means the current directory;

`../` means the parent of the current directory.

Answer (score 7):

Just start it with a slash?  This means root.  As long as you're testing on a web server (e.g. localhost) and not a file system (e.g. C:) then that should be all you need to do.

Comment: huh? doesnt that just check the local folder?

Comment: No, that would be ./ or nothing at all.

Comment: Are you on windows?  It's quite easy to set up a local web server like XAMPP.  But if you just want client-side features you could just use the DOS command SUBST to put your root folder on its own virtual drive letter:  E.g. SUBST W: c:\myprojects\projectx\wwwroot - then you can just have href="/style/style.css" (or wherever style.css resides in your folder structure - load up explorer and see what's in W:).  Then load W:\folder\index.html in your browser (some browsers will rewrite this to file:///W:/folder/index.html).

Comment: yes im on windows- i just want to do edits out of dreamweaver template and check my progress without having to save over onto the server 50000 times

Comment: So, have you tried the subst command so you can see your site on your machine under W: ?

Comment: i dont understad what that command is, or where to use it(but from what it sounds, it will cease to work once i load it to my webserver, which is not what i want)-  i tried setting up xampp, and got it to load locally, but using / as a root for style link didnt seem to work

Comment: It won't cease to work because your URLs will start with a slash and not contain 'W:'.  Subst is a DOS command, you just need to open a command prompt.  If you're using XAMPP now, then what happens when you request http://localhost/style.css ?  Is that even where your stylesheet is hosted?

Answer (score 5):

This is oddly confusing to me. I know it shouldn't be. To check my understanding, I'd like to use a family relations model to compare. Assuming "You" is the current webpage, is the following correct?

```
<img src="picture.jpg">            In your folder with you, like a sibling
<img src="images/picture.jpg">     In your child's folder, under you
<img src="../picture.jpg">         In your parent's folder, above you
<img src="/images/picture.jpg">    In your cousin's folder
```

So, up to parent, over to sibling, down to their child = your cousin, named "images".

Comment: The cousin analogy is faulty.  When you use the / at the start of the reference, you are pointing to your docroot.  It becomes full path addressing instead of relative addressing.

Answer (score 1):

As [Alexander Jank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2737565/alexander-jank) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42997313/11573842) `<base href="http://www.example.com/default/">` is great. When using sub-domains e.g. `default.example.com`  base works great, because the JS and CSS loads from the said sub-domain and is accessible to both `default.example.com` and `example.com/default`

When using the root path, and your JS and CSS files are located in `example.com/css`, or `example.com/js`, then the subdomain has no access and the root of the subdomain is not accessible, except using the base.

Answer (score -3):

Use two periods before `/`, example:

```
../style.css
```

Comment: A bad idea, because `../` won't give you the URL relative to the root directory, but changes depending on the current file's directory.

Answer (score -6):

You can use [ResolveUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx)

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Content/table-sorter.css")%>" />
```

Comment: This presupposes the user and the page itself is interpreted server side by ASP.NET.  When pre-supposing these kinds of things it's very important you be explicit about those assumptions.

Comment: As stated, this is very specific solution for ASP.NET pages but it is exactly the solution I needed for a similar issue I have regarding pages (located at different levels from root) accessing the same resource.