# Why isn't CSS being ran on HTML file?

Tags: html, css

Working on a project and I currently have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
       <title>Jams</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,600,700,300">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/normalize.css/normalize.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
    </head>
```

My directory is

```
jams  
|---- musicplayer[index.html]  
|---- styles  
|     |---- main.css  
|     |---- normalize.css(folder)  
|     |     |---- normalize.css(file)
```

Sorry if the directory might seem confusing but it mainly states that jams is the parent folder and the rest of the folder are inside, with the brackets being the files inside the folders. The only exception is normalize.css where that's a folder inside of styles, and inside of the normalize.css folder is a normalize.css file.

Comment: Have you tried prepending a `/` meaning relative to the website root?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713295/specify-a-root-path-of-your-html-directory-for-script-links?rq=1

Comment: normalize.css folder is under styles folder?

Comment: The code you have should work fine based on your description of the structure. Use the developer tools in your browser. Check the console for errors. Check the Network tab to see what the request actually got back (e.g. maybe you had a permissions error)

Comment: @s.k.Soni yes it is

Comment: @Quentin got it, thanks! I got 3 error messages saying that the CSS files are not found, but they're there.

Comment: Why would you name your folder `normalize.css` ?

Answer (score 1):

In the inspector window, right click on the stylesheet link and select `open in new tab`

From there you will be able to see the full url of where the page was trying to pull your CSS from. That should give you a better idea of what you need to do to fix it.

Also, I would try adding `./` to the beginning of the href.   i.e. `href="./styles/main.css"`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

edit the line

href="styles/normalize.css/normalize.css and
href="styles/main.css

replace this two line with

href="./styles/normalize.css/normalize.css" and
href="./styles/main.css"