# javascript file only loading on root page

Tags: html, express, express-handlebars

I am using ExpressJS with hbs view engine. I was using hbs to pass a script src to the view, the string I was passing was "app/app.js".

The problem I encountered was, when on https://localhost/ it would load app.js, however when on http://localhost/dashboard, it would fail to load app.js.

I figured out it was because I was missing the opening / and corrected it to "/app/app.js", but I have no idea why it would work on the index page but not a sub page.
Can someone please explain this inconsistency to me?

Thanks

Comment: Where `app` folder located? when using / it goes to the root of that web. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713295/specify-a-root-path-of-your-html-directory-for-script-links

Comment: If you could post some code, it would be great :)